# How do I Check search keyword in the URL

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am a beginner in Selenium. I wanted to know how I can verify the URL against the keyword I entered in the search bar.

The search page url is `https://catalog-mytest.com/search?`

When I entered redcar in the search bar and hit enter, the url becomes `https://catalog-mytest.com/search?keywords=redcar`

Could you guide me on how to write a piece of code that would verify the URL with the keywords? thank you.

Comment: I think you want driver.getCurrentURL();  You can then split on the question mark, and split each part by equal sign.  Also consider HTMLEncodings when comparing.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two approaches-

**Approach-1:**

```
String url = Driver.getCurrentUrl();
boolean passed = url.contains("your keyword here");
if (passed) {
    System.out.println("Test Passed");
} else {
    System.out.println("Test Failed");
    Assert.fail("This message will be printed in stacktrace if the assertion fails.");
}
```

This is the simplest way of doing this.

**Approach-2:**

```
String keyword = Driver.getCurrentUrl().split("?")[1].split("=")[1];
boolean passed = keyword.equals("your keyword here");
if (passed) {
    System.out.println("Test Passed");
} else {
    System.out.println("Test Failed");
    Assert.fail("This message will be printed in stacktrace if the assertion fails.");
}
```

> This approach can be error prone, if the URL does not always contain
>   `?`, `=` in it then the test can fail with
>   `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: what would be the best approach to add the if and else statement to have it print out Pass and Fail if the url has the specified keyword or not?

Comment: @SeleniumNewbie if your requirement is to only verify the keyword in the url (not to store it and use it somewhere else) I would suggest to go with Approach-1.

Comment: I see, thank you so much for the help, is there a way to print out Fail or passed?

Comment: @SeleniumNewbie I've edited the answer based on your need, take a look. If you do not want the execution to be stopped on failure, comment Assertion lines.

Comment: Thank you so much!